# Running another python program from python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to build a test script to test my python code.

The tested code should read from stdin and write to stdout.

The tester code should call the tested code passing the values in a file as stdin, and read stdout to compare with the expected values (stored in another file)

Tested code:

```
n = int(input())
x1,y1 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())) 
x2,y2 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())) 

#what it does is really not importante
if ((min(x1, x2) <= n/2) and (max(x1, x2) > n/2) or
    (min(y1, y2) <= n/2) and (max(y1, y2) > n/2)):
    print('S')
else :
    print ('N')
```

Tester code:

```
import os
import subprocess as sp
inputs = os.listdir("./warmup_tests/warmup_B/input")
for ipt in inputs:
    with open('./warmup_tests/warmup_B/input/{}'.format(ipt)) as f:
        res = (sp.run(['python', 'b.py'], stdin=f, capture_output=True))
```

I have received multiple of the following error (when disabling capture_output to better visualization):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "b.py", line 10, in <module>
    x1,y1 = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())) 
  File "<string>", line 1
    5 2
      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

My input file is the following:

```
10
5 2
5 1
```

The above works when there is only one `input()` on the tested code. What am I missing for making it work with multiple `input()`?

Comment: Why are you doing it twice? x1 y1 x2 y2? When you call the input file you will only have 3 lines so the 4th will be eof?

Comment: `input()` should read only one line. I've replaced all the tester code for `print( input() )` and that prints only the first line of input, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is work for me (with small changes). It works and with `capture_output=True`, and with `capture_output=False`

https://drive.google.com/open?id=16NK1_Qfdd98prpmBUqaP894j8uGTNdnf

command to run:

```
python3 tester.py
```

For your problem: I suspect in your input files can missing '\n' in some lines (may be editor bug, don't know).

Also try check indents in your module `b.py`

Can you share your code with input files for detailed analysing?